# How to use Coroutines and Callback properly? Retrieving an array out of an IEnumerator

Tags: c#, arrays, callback, delegates, ienumerator

we have some trouble with an IEnumerator and don't know how to retrieve an array out of it. We found out that you have to do it with a callback , but we don't really know how to use it. Here is the code of the IEnumerator and the void that needs to receive a string array from it.

```
public void StartRoutineGetProjects(string username, string password, string url){
    StartCoroutine(GetProjects(username, password, url));

    // here we dont know how to receive the array, need some help here
}

public IEnumerator GetProjects (string username, string password, string url, Action<string[]> callback)
{
    string privateURL = "http://" + url + "/Unity/myprojects.php";

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
    form.AddField ("username", username);
    form.AddField ("password", password);

    // Send WWWForm
    WWW projects_get = new WWW (privateURL, form);

    if (projects_get.error != null && projects_get.error != "") {
        Debug.Log ("Internal Error");
    } else {
        // splitting the result at "|"
        string[] tempProjects = projects_get.text.Split ("|".ToCharArray ());

        yield return tempProjects;

        callback(tempProjects) // <-- here we want to return the array

    }
}
```

We would be glad for every help we can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED] Yes finally it works. Thank you very much. We don't want to withhold our solution, so others can benefit from it.
So here is the code.
First the databasescript:

```
        public void StartRoutineCheckLoginCorrect (string username, string password, string url, Action<string[]> callback)
    {
        StartCoroutine (Login (username, password, url, callback));
    }

    IEnumerator Login (string username, string password, string url,Action<string[]> callback)
    {
        string loginURL = "http://" + url + "/Unity/mylogin.php";
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
        form.AddField ("username", username);
        form.AddField ("password", password);

        WWW users_get = new WWW (loginURL, form);

        yield return users_get;

        if (users_get.error != null && users_get.error != "") {
            Debug.Log ("Login failed");

        } else {
            string[] temp = users_get.text.Split ("*".ToCharArray ());

            if (temp.Length <= 2 || temp [0].ToString () == "Username or password false") {
                Debug.Log (temp [0].ToString ());
                login = false;
            } else {
                Debug.Log ("Login succeeded");
                login = true;
                callback (temp);
            }
        }
    }

    public void StartRoutineGetProjects(string id, string username, string url, Action<string[]> callback){
        StartCoroutine (GetProjects (id, username, url,callback));
    }

    public IEnumerator GetProjects (string id, string username, string url, Action<string[]> callback)
    {
        string privateURL = "http://" + url + "/Unity/myprojects.php";

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
        form.AddField ("id", id);
        form.AddField ("username", username);

        WWW projects_get = new WWW (privateURL, form);

        yield return projects_get;

        if (projects_get.error != null && projects_get.error != "") {
            Debug.Log ("Internal error");
            callback (null);
        } else {
            string[] tempProjects = projects_get.text.Split ("|".ToCharArray ());

            callback (tempProjects);

        }
    }
```

Second the Loginscript: Here we get Access to the variables from the databasescript.

```
    public void LoginStart ()
{
    StartCoroutine (Login ());
}

IEnumerator Login ()
{
    userName = inputUsername.text;
    password = inputPassword.text;

    string[] userData = null;
    bool wait2 = true;
    dbscript.StartRoutineCheckLoginCorrect (userName, password, url,(callback) =>{
        userData = callback;
        wait2 = false;
    });

    while (wait2) {
        yield return null;
    }

    id = userData [0];

    string[] stringArray = null;
    bool wait = true;
    dbscript.StartRoutineGetProjects (id, userName, url, (callback) => {
        stringArray = callback;
        wait = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StartCoroutine(GetProjects(username, password, url, (tempProjectArray) => 
{
    // do stuff with your project array
}));
```

or

```
void OnProjectRetrieved(string[] projects)
{
    // do stuff with your project array
}

public void StartRoutineGetProjects(string username, string password, string url)
{
    StartCoroutine(GetProjects(username, password, url, OnProjectRetrieved));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help, I changed my code as you said.
Unfortunately I missed something in my first post. The void function is a string[]-function as well, that shall pass the array to another script. Here is the code , how it looks now. I have to return the string[] somehow , but i don't know exactly where to do this.

```
    public string[] StartRoutineGetProjects(string username, string password, string url){
    string[] temp;

    StartCoroutine(GetProjects(username, password, url,(stringArray)=>{
        temp = stringArray;
    }));
}

public IEnumerator GetProjects (string username, string password, string url, Action<string[]> callback)
{
    string privateURL = "http://" + url + "/Unity/myprojects.php";

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
    form.AddField ("username", username);
    form.AddField ("password", password);

    // send WWWForm
    WWW projects_get = new WWW (privateURL, form);

    // Receiving projects
    yield return projects_get;

    if (projects_get.error != null && projects_get.error != "") {
        Debug.Log ("Interner Fehler");
        callback (null);
    } else {
        // splitting the result at "|"
        string[] tempProjekte = projects_get.text.Split ("|".ToCharArray ());

        callback (tempProjekte);
    }
}
```